# Prevent questions from starting "So"

Tags: feature-request

So, am I the only one who has noticed that a lot of new questions now start like a bad standup routine from the 90's?

> "So I was writing this code the other day"

Or maybe they are addressing StackOverflow in some cases (SO), but eitherway it's unnecessary.

At the very least can it be trimmed from the question preview so a little more text that is actually relevent can be seen?

[image: Example]

Comment: That sounds like Dane Cook bad. I'm personally more worried about Andrew Dice Clay bad.

Comment: -1 because you didn't start the question with "So,"

Comment: Is this such a widespread and egregious problem that we have to create another filter which may backfire in legitimate cases? There are a *lot more* stylistic issues in many questions that we should care about (but hardly can, because checking for style is virtually impossible).

Comment: The problem is not "So," ... the problem is "So I was writing this code the other day". This whole part has to go, it's noise. Edit the question to remove the noise if the question is worth it - all the noise, not just the useless "So" that's at the beginning. ;)

Comment: @TinyGiant I couldn't bring myself to do it!

Comment: Like, that's just your opinion, man.

Comment: [It is "Stack Overflow", not "StackOverflow"](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance) (the last section, "Proper Use of the Stack Exchange Name"). Please edit your question.

Comment: @PeterMortensen you can edit it also Peter.

Answer (score 7):

This is just a symptom of people writing the way they talk.

They feel uncomfortable standing up in a room full of people and just starting in on their question. They feel they need some kind of transition or segue, just like the 1990s comedian. You'll notice that if you work in an office, and a coworker decides to come interrupt you with a question, they will often start that conversation with "So…", too. It's a filler word being misappropriated as an introduction or transition. The perception is that it is somehow less rude to interrupt someone when you start with this delicate little word than if you just start yammering about your actual question.

I will grant that it is terrible, horrible, awful, no-good grammar, and that it grates like fingernails on a chalkboard to me. But I'm not a big fan of automated blacklists, either. A few posts that need manual editing is the lesser of two evils. The odds are very high that an initial "So" is not the only thing that needs to be fixed in the post.

Comment: Still... its better than people just standing next to you in silence, hoping you are the one to break the silence...

Comment: Yes. Fortunately, those are not the only two approaches available.

Comment: Your quiet write theirs usually moor bad grandma too correct

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with this feature request.

People have different styles in talking, writing and expressing themselves. It's more important to focus on content rather than wording, having "So" doesn't bother me, and I even don't edit it, unless in rare cases were it really doesn't belong there.

Comment: Wording _is_ content, and Stack Overflow is not a place to "express yourself".